# C# Using user defined datatype from dll that is referenced by an dll that is referenced

Tags: c#

Is it possible to use a datatype in c# which is given in a.dll which is referenced by wrapper.dll which is referenced by my project?

size in dimensions.dll > reference > wrapper.dll > reference > MyProject

dimensions.dll:

```
namespace Dimensions
{
    class Size : Someclass
    {
        public int length { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
        public size() {
            height = 0;
            width = 0;
            length = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

wrapper.dll:

```
using Dimensions
namespace wrapper
{
    
    class DimensionsWrapper
    {
        public DimensionsWrapper(size){
            // do something in constructor
        }
    }
}
```

myProject:

```
using wrapper
class Programm {
    // size is not available
    size mySize = new size();
    mySize.length = 5;
    mySize.height= 6;
    mySize.width = 7;
    
    DimensionsWrapper myVar = new DimensionsWrapper(mySize);
}
```

I **don't** like to reference dimensions.dll in MyProject,
but I need to use the size class in MyProject.

Many Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Comment: @YungDeiza Would you please tell me how? =D

Comment: @2letuknow can you please edit your post? Add the code where you have tried to achieve your objective and describe exactly what didn't work.

Comment: The C# compiler is going to force you to reference a.dll, resistance is futile.

Comment: @IVSoftware Yes, sure!

Answer (score 0):

You must include both `wrapper.dll` and `dimensions.dll` as references in your project, so the build tools knows about all the types you're using. But in your own code you only need the `using` directive for the `wrapper` namespace.